# Перенос слов "солью, бельё, крылья"

Tags: орфография, перенос

Как переносить слова типа: *солью, бельё, крылья*?

Answer (score 2):

Такие слова переносить не рекомендуется вообще. Но если уж без переноса никак не обойтись, то: *со-лью, бе-лье, кры-лья*.